# how to import my.sqlite3 into my iPhone project in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I drag locationsWOW.sqlite3 file into my project and trying to load it in.The console did't show info about `NSLog(@"failed to open database!")`; but show `NSLog(@"database open");`
And even when I change the name of `locationsWOW` to be locations `(@"locations" ofType:@"sqlite3"];)`
which is not existing ,still the project successfully compiled and my .sqlite database didn't work.Any could help me a beginner.

Here is my code.

```
-(id)init{
if (self = [super init]) {

    NSString *sqlite3DB = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"locationsWOW" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

    if (sqlite3_open([sqlite3DB UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"failed to open database!");
    }
}
NSLog(@"database open");

return self;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more clarification to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginer just do the following steps in your code

```
+(NSString *)databasePath

 {

   NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   NSString *sql_Path=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString *dbPath=[sql_Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locationsWOW.sqlite"];

   NSFileManager *fileMgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

   BOOL success;

   NSError *error;

   success=[fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

   if (!success) {

    NSString *path=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locationsWOW.sqlite"];

    success=[fileMgr copyItemAtPath:path toPath:dbPath error:&error];

   }

   return dbPath;
  }
```

After when create the Table

```
+(void)createTable
{
  char *error;

  NSString *filePath =[self databasePath];

  if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)

  {

     NSString *strQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableName(id TEXT,name TEXT);"];

     sqlite3_exec(database, [strQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);

  }

  else

  {

    NSAssert(0, @"Table failed to create");

    NSLog(@"TableName Table Not Created");

  }

  sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Comment: Hi Thx to your help.But still it didn't work. My Project Named 'sqlite3Test' , and locationsWOW.sqlite file locations in root of Folder 'sqlite3Test'.What's the problem?Thx.

Comment: That is not a issue.locationsWOW.sqlite is SQLite database name.